# Paintbrush won't give flat colour

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm going out of my mind with this one. Actually, I have two problems, but I'll get to the other ones in a different post. Right so I'm using Photoshop Elements 14 and any time I try to use a color brush that's anything but black or white it goes all oily and I can't seem to get a flat color no matter what I do. Here's an example of the effect.

[image]

The brush modes I'm using are in Normal mode and there's no scattering or anything applied in the settings. I'm using a Basic Brush. Please help, I don't know what's causing this or how to rectify it.

Comment: Looks like color dynamics - hue shift. I don't use Elements so that's the best I can offer.

Comment: I don't use Elements either, but the full version of Photoshop has a mixer brush that would create a similar effect.  Does Elements have a mixer brush perhaps?  If so, try selecting the ordinary brush tool.